# Maximizing the COX likelihood function

Tags: math, optimization, mathematical-optimization, mle, log-likelihood

What are the best optimization methods to find the parameter values that maximize the likelihood function of COX specifically ?
The likelihood function of COX is:

[The likelihood function of COX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgYaZ.png)

How can we judge if a certain optimization method is the most adequate in this specific case?

I tried the Newton-Raphson Method.
Im looking for the most adequate method to do MLE for the COX Likelihood function.